# How do PHP based sites serve different versions of the site?

Tags: php

If I had a site designed for desktop web usage, but I wanted to do create a version with a mobile-oriented design, how would I go about displaying this without maintaining two versions of the page with very similar logic behind them.

I can't just used different CSS for the mobile version as I plan to serve a different HTML structure, is there a better way than just using a lot of if statements in each page?

Answer (score 3):

You would have two versions for the site, one for a desktop, another one for mobile devices. Then depending on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you'd redirect a user.

For instance:

```
<?php

// Let's define a function to make it easier to read
function is_mobile(){
 $list = array('Android', 'Iphone'); // Add more yourself

 foreach ($mobile as $agent) {
    if (stripos($agent, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
        // Looks like mobile
        return true; 
      }
  }
  // Assuming desktop by default
  return false;
}

// Then before rendering a template, you'd it approach like this:
if (is_mobile()) {
   require 'mobile.php';
} else {
  require 'desktop.php';
}
```

Comment: if you are going to require the same model for both versions, it's better to load it out of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to implement a template system like Smarty or Zend View (there are many out there). From your main site, your controller code would perform all of the logic for you and assign values to the template variables. Then depending on what version (desktop/mobile) is being used to view your site, load the appropriate template files. These could have very different HTML/CSS rules and structure, while still using the same PHP logic before ever rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way than just using a lot of if statements in each page?

Yes, there is a much better way. Unfortunately, it would have been a lot easier if you designed your site with this in mind. What you can do is use a template engine to keep your PHP code and actual content completely separate. So, if you want to alter / add some new client pages, this would be very simple. You would just add stuff to your templates. You can also choose which templates to load based on the user's user agent string (which includes OS information). The PHP itself would only be responsible for getting data from your database / files / wherever dynamic data is obtained.

Take a look at the many [template engines for PHP](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/) that are out there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used code like the example below to determine if a user is mobile to redirect to a mobile version of the site. The site uses the same Model and Controller files but uses different View files.

```
if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    or strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0 
    or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))
)
{
    header('location: /m/index.php');
    exit();
}
```